# Data get removed from column 1 when write data in column 2 using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

Here is my code :

```
    public static String[] array1 = {"devu","xyz","test","bb","run"};
    public static String[] array2 = {"dvu","yz","tet","b","run"};


 String excelFileName = "C:/Users/admin/IdeaProjects/Google_Demo/Write1.xlsx";//name of excel file

        String sheetName = "Sheet1";//name of sheet

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName);

        //iterating r number of rows
        for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);

            //iterating c number of columns
            for (int c = 0; c < 1; c++) {
                if (!row.equals(null)) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);

                cell.setCellValue(array1[r]);

            }
        }}



        int count1 = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
            XSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(r);


            //iterating c number of columns
            for (int c = 2; c < 3; c++) {

                if (row1.equals(null)) {
                    row1 = sheet.createRow(count1);
                }
                    XSSFCell cell = row1.createCell(c);


                    cell.setCellValue(array2[r]);
                    count1++;

                }


            }

            FileOutputStream fileOut1 = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);

            //write this workbook to an Outputstream.
            wb.write(fileOut1);
            //fileOut.flush();
            fileOut1.close();
        }
```

I have taken 2 arrays and writing data to excel using Selenium webdriver and POI.

It works fine If I write data of only first array but as soon as loop of second array run, it deletes data from first column of excel and write only data of second array in new column.

Comment: The "create" methods `createRow` and `createCell` are doing exactly what they say. They **create** **new** rows or cells which are empty after that. So if there are already rows or cells filled from `array1`, then  you should **not** new creating those rows or cells for filling them from `array2`. Instead you should **get** them using the "get" methods `getRow` and `getCell`. Surely you have  to check whether you have gotten something and if not, **then** create it. There is a helper class [CellUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html) to solve exactly this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are again creating a new `row` in second `for loop`. Below line should be removed to make your code work as per stated behavior -

```
XSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(r);
```

Below is the complete updated code -

```
public static String[] array1 = {"devu","xyz","test","bb","run"};
public static String[] array2 = {"dvu","yz","tet","b","run"};
String excelFileName = "C:/Users/admin/IdeaProjects/Google_Demo/Write1.xlsx";//name of excel file

String sheetName = "Sheet1";//name of sheet

XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName);
//iterating r number of rows
for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);
    //iterating c number of columns
    for (int c = 0; c < 1; c++) {
            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);
            cell.setCellValue(array1[r]);

    }
}
for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
    // As per current input and code, this if block will never execute. 
    // However, adding it so that later, if first for loop will change, this code can work.
    if(row == null){
        row = sheet.createRow(r);        
    } 
    //iterating c number of columns
    for (int c = 2; c < 3; c++) {
        XSSFCell cell = row1.createCell(c);
        cell.setCellValue(array2[r]);
    }
}

FileOutputStream fileOut1 = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);
//write this workbook to an Outputstream.
wb.write(fileOut1);
//fileOut.flush();
fileOut1.close();
```